# Second Lie algebra cohomology with values in $\mathbb{R}$ is finite dimensional- reference request

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces, representation-theory, lie-algebras

While studying projective representations of Lie groups, I have come to the notion of Lie algebra cohomology. $H^2({\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R}})$ is in bijective correspondence with equivalence classes of central extensions of $\mathfrak{g}$ by $\mathbb{R}$. I have come to the conclusion, that $H^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R})$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, as it is the quotient of two $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces (which inherit pointwise addition and multiplication). I would like to conclude that for any finite-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ (need not be simple,semisimple or anything), there exists some $n  \in \mathbb{N}$, such that as groups, or as vector spaces it holds that
\begin{equation}
H^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n}.
\end{equation}
In order to obtain this conclusion, I would need a statement/proof of the fact that for any finite dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, its second cohomology group is finite dimensional. Then, upon the choice of a basis, I could show that it is isomorphic to some $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, as it is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Where can I find such a reference, or how could I prove this?

Comment: Have a look at the explicit construction of Lie algebra cohomology via the de Rham complex -- this immediately implies the finite-dimensionality you are after.

Comment: I tried searching (in the books I know- I have a mathematical physics background, not pure math), but everywhere I see the construction comes from cocycles, and is related to projective representations (Schottenloher, Bargmann, etc.) - could you please give a reference where the second Lie algebra cohomology is defined via DeRham cohomology and how can I see that this is related to cocycles?

Comment: See my [lecture notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_76_coho.pdf), page $45-48$. Of course, ${\rm Alt}(\mathfrak{g}^2,\Bbb R)$ is finite-dimensional, so the claim follows.

Comment: Dear Dietrich, Thank you very much. To make it sure I understood, I would like to clarify the argument as I understand it. The idea is that both $Z^{2}(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R})$ and $B^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R})$ are finite-dimensional, as they are both subspaces of $Alt(\mathfrak{g}^2,\mathbb{R})$, which is finite dimensional. This follows from the fact that we chose finite-dimensional Lie algebras, say they are $n$ dimensional. Then $Alt(\mathfrak{g}^2,\mathbb{R})$ is of the dimension $\frac{n!}{(n-2)! 2!}=\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$?

Comment: Can we say a stronger statement? Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra of dimension $n$. Then $H^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{m}$ for some $m$, we proved this. Can we actually precisely say for which m this holds, in terms of n?

Comment: Yes, often we can. But it depends on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. If it is semisimple, then $H^2(\mathfrak{g},\Bbb R)=0$.

Comment: That's right. That's Whitehead's lemma. Is there no such general statement for an arbitrary finite dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$? I.e. what is the most general statement one can make on $m$ given some (say weak) conditions on $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: There are only estimates in general. For nilpotent Lie algebras this number $m$, the second Betti number, has to be at least $2$, but can be quite large, e.g., for Heisenberg Lie algebras $\mathfrak{h}_{2n+1}$ it is $m=\binom{2n}{2}-1$.